# Update Data in a RandomAccessFile in Java

Tags: java, file, arraylist, randomaccessfile

I have a problem with my code, I'm trying to change the data of a given RandomAccessFile and an Object, it's more about deleting that occurrence. Here's the first part:

```
public void updateData(File file,InfoPlayers player) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt", file.getParentFile());
        RandomAccessFile f= new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charset));
        
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;){
            if(!line.contains(player.getMail())){
                System.out.println("line"+line);
                wbyte(f, line);//this functions writes the bytes of an given string
            }
        }
        
        file.delete();
        temp.renameTo(file);
     
    }
```

So, in order to write in the RAF I have this function, all the info that i write in the files are ArrayList<ArrayList>, (this part is important)... to do so, i have a look alike version of the following method

```
public void wbyte(RandomAccessFile file,String str) throws IOException{
        byte[] byt=str.getBytes();
        for(byte byteWrite : byt){
            file.writeByte(byteWrite);
        }
        file.writeUTF("\n");
        
    }
```

Everything's fine, until I found out that the last line of the file still has some info (repeated info). Here's an example before the update: [image: before the update]

And after the updating [image: after the updating]

If you see, it's like garbage. Any help would be appreciated :)
PS: If you need more code, just tell me, but this is almost all I use to write in the file

Comment: This cannot possibly work unless the replacement data is exactly the same size as what it is replacing. Your mixture of `writeByte()` and `writeUTF()` is also problematic. You need to rethink your requirement. You will almost certainly have to update the file via father-son update.

Comment: "update the file via father-son update"? What is it about? I've never heard of it

Comment: Copy the data up to the point to want to change it, write the replacement, skip past that point in the input, copy the rest of the file, close and rename the files.

Comment: Ok, I made some changes and thank you for the clarification about writeByte() and writeUTF()